# Binary runs in terminal but not in xcode simulator. When using the source code I get the same error

Tags: ios, c, xcode, terminal, dlopen

I'm using system() to call an executable binary that runs perfectly fine in the terminal, but does not work in the iOS simulator.  I get a runtime error.

The error that I'm getting is:

dyld: unloaded: /software/evpath-4.dev/lib/libcmselect.so
  dlopen() failed, error: 'dlopen(libcmselect.so, 1): 
Library not loaded: libcercs_env.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /software/evpath-4.dev/lib/libcmselect.so
  Reason: image not found'
dlerror()
Failed to load required select dll.
Search path includes '.', '/usr/local/pkg/working/evpath_base/nightly_build_area/evpath/build', '/software/evpath-4.dev/lib' and any default search paths supported by ld.so

I also have the source code for the binary.  I imported all the header files and all the libraries pertaining to the source code.  It also builds successfully, but when I try and execute it, it gives me the same error.

Gaurd Malloc is unchecked and I've tried adding a Run Script in the Build Phases that sets all the environments that would have been set given I had run it in a terminal shell.

Comment: When running from Xcode, the working directory will be the root. When running from Terminal, it'll be the current directory. Could this be the problem?

Comment: No that's not the problem.  I think the problem is that xcode cannot find the library path.  I just tested that it gave me the same error in terminal when I did not set the environments.  As I said though, I tried to set the environment using the Run Script in XCode.  I also tried having system run a terminal command that set the environments and called my program, but that didn't work either.

Comment: If the library is present under iOS, then add it's directory search parth to the linker options.  You can set a runpath, so environment isn't required.